# Copy files from GitHub using remote() and copy to directory while being able to excluding some files

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I want to be able to pull files from a GitHub zip file using remote() or something similar and then copy the files to a directory.
I want to also be able to exclude some files from being copied, which could be by means of an array.

For example: I want to get the master version of laravel (github.com/laravel/laravel) and copy over all the files apart from this array:

```
['.gitignore', 'readme.md', 'CONTRIBUTING.md', 'phpunit.xml', 'package.json', 'gulpfile.js', 'public/css', 'public/fonts', 'public/favicon.ico']
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [mem-fs-editor](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor) glob helpers to match and ignore patterns while copying the files over.

You can probably fetch your git repo using npm (`package.json` dependencies with git), this will make easier to use.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. Being .src is deprecated how do I pass those files to the copy command? The reason I am not using npm is there are different options in my yeoman generator for PHP frameworks and I pull from what ever repo was selected. Otherwise that is the best option.

Comment: @zizther You can fetch both options via npm. Install time is probably already slow, better to incur the download test during that step.

Comment: Thanks Simon. There will be multiple BE options in the future. I don't want to have to download all of them at the start, only the one required. If I am not looking to copy the files, presumably I want to move them, using remote places them in a cache, is it best to copy them from there or move them? Would remote.cachePath gives the 'from' parameter?

Comment: Yes, `cachePath` would do it.